# Invalid source release: 1.8 on jenkins in SBT

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, sbt

I'm working on setting up a build on jenkins.

The distribution is Centos 7 x64, Using sbt 0.13.7 and Play framework 2.3.6(if that has any relevance).

Java 8 is installed properly:

```
bash-4.2$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

SBT has, what I assume, a proper config to compile to Java 8.

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")
```

And still I get this error during `sbt compile`

```
[info] Compiling 13 Scala sources and 18 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/super-webapp/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] javac: invalid source release: 1.8
[error] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

I'm no linux expert, so is there anything I need to be aware environment related to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Check the JDK version Jenkins is using for that particular build. It maybe using a system-installed Java 6 or 7, particularly if you installed Jenkins before Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Tinkered around the JAVA_HOME settings which didn't solve the problem, but because SBT was ignoring it.

I've set this in the `built.sbt`:

```
javaHome := Some(file("/opt/jdk1.8.0_25/"))
```

And the build went through.

This is satisfactory for now.